# Square law device using FPGA

Tags: fpga, verilog

I am trying to implement Square Law Device on Virtex 5 Family FPGA but before burning it to the FPGA I was trying to simulate it in the Xilinx ISE kit. I am not sure whether the code is correct or not but here is the procedure I followed:

1. Created the schematic
2. Generated and Instatiated the IP Cores for Binary Counter (just for simulation purpose) and Sine Wave Generator using Cordic
3. Inserted a Verilog Test Fixture.

But I was not successful in simulating it. I am inserting the code for the Verilog Test Fixture.

```
// Verilog test fixture created from schematic F:\Xilinx\demod\demod\schema.sch - Wed May 01 19:16:25 2013

`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module schema_schema_sch_tb();

// Inputs
   reg clk;

// Output
   wire [35:0] outp;

// Bidirs

// Instantiate the UUT
    schema UUT (
    .outp(outp), 
    .clk(clk)
   );

// Initialize Inputs
   `ifdef auto_init
         initial begin
             clk = 0;
                 repeat(100) begin
                     #10 clk = 1;
                     #10 clk = 0;
                 end
         end         
   `endif
endmodule
```

Also I am copying the schematic of the project.

[image: Schematic of the Project]
Where am I wrong?

Edit: The multiplier element is red just because it got selected while taking snapshot. I tried removing the instiantion of IP cores and I got some output but not the correct one. After that I replaced the `always begin` loop with `repeat(16) begin` loop, but it shows an *error* near **repeat**.

Comment: What did you expect to see, and what did you see instead? Also, you're probably going to need to provide a reset signal to reset modules that have internal state to a known state. Does the UUT really have no inputs other than a clock?

Comment: @DaveTweed The UUT was instantiated when I generated a Verilog Test Fixture from the schematic. I have no clue about the RESET thing but from schematic I am sure it doesn't have any other input.

Comment: why are the components internal to the UUT also instantiated in the testbench? surely you would just instantiate the uut?

Comment: @StaceyAnne does that mean I don't have instantiate the multiplier, counter and sine_wave?

Comment: @StaceyAnne I removed the other instantiating code but the output is not the one I want. Because of which I changed the code a little. Instead of running the loop forever I tried `repeat` loop, but it shows an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your `initial begin` block does not have an `end`, so you're getting a syntax error.

If you see errors past this, then please put the full text of the error into your question.

Comment: I'm still getting the error. The error is: `ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "F:/Xilinx/demod/demod/test_module.v" Line 30: Syntax error near "repeat"`.

Comment: The code in your post does not show that you've fixed this error. If you have an error message you need to post that with the **exact** code that's given you the error.

Comment: its the exact code that's giving me the error.

Comment: @mozart, the repeat block needs to be inside the initial block. `initial begin clk=0; repeat(16) begin #10 clk=1; #10 clk=0; end /*for repeat*/ end /*for initial*/`

Comment: @Greg now the clk is shown undefined (_red_ signal). Logically your syntax is correct according to the online sources. Thanks for help but what to do now?

Comment: @mozart Did you define `auto_init` for your ifdef?

Comment: @Tim I have updated the code now. You can see that I am using `auto_init`.

Answer (score 0):

With The code in the current state, unless you have another file for compiler option on that defines `auto_init`, then the repeat block will be ignored by the compiler. If you want `clk` to be initialized to `0` in some conditions and `X` and others, then your initial block should look like this.

```
// Initialize Inputs
initial begin
  `ifdef auto_init
    clk = 0; // clk is 0 if auto_init is defined, otherwise default(i.e. X)
  `endif
  /* repeat block is outside the ifdef and still inside the initial block. 
   * Will run regardless of the ifdef result */
  repeat(100) begin
    #10 clk = 1;
    #10 clk = 0;
  end
end
```

If you want `clk` to initialize to `0`, then the compile must read in `` `define auto_init `` before it sees `` `ifdef auto_init ``. Alternatively, you should be able to define `auto_init` from your compiler command line option. You will need to refer to your user manual as it is can be different between venders.